# How to get the URL to an embedded resource in play dist

Tags: java, playframework, embedded-resource

I'm using the play framework (2.2) and I want to load jar files in a URLClassLoader so i can use multiple version of the same library.

```java
private static final ClassLoader classloader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{
            Play.application().resource("path/to/file.jar")
    }, ThisClass.class.getClassLoader());
```

This will work in development, because the path to the jar file can be retrieved, but when creating a distribution with `play dist`

this doesn't work anymore because `Play.application().resource()` will return `null`.

How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

`Play.application().resource()` doesn't work in `play dist` version, but `Play.application().resourceAsStream()` does.

This will return the resource as a `InputStream`, not an `URL`. 
You'll have to find ways of using the InputStream in stead of the URL.

One possibility could be to write the InputStream to a file, and then get the URL to the file.

I wrote a JarClassLoader that handles InputStreams for loading classes (the jar files and the classes are loaded into memory):

```java
public class JarClassLoader extends SecureClassLoader{

    private Hashtable<String, byte[]> classes = new Hashtable<>();
    private Hashtable<String, Class> loadedClasses = new Hashtable<>();

    JarClassLoader(InputStream[] jarFiles, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
        try {
            for (InputStream jarFile : jarFiles) {
                JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(jarFile);
                JarEntry entry = jis.getNextJarEntry();
                while(entry != null) {
                    if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(jis);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        int bytes = bis.read();
                        while (bytes != -1) {
                            baos.write(bytes);
                            bytes = bis.read();
                        }
                        classes.put(entry.getName().substring(0, entry.getName().length() - 6).replace("/", "."), baos.toByteArray());
                    }
                    entry = jis.getNextJarEntry();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            classes = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (loadedClasses.containsKey(name)) {
            return loadedClasses.get(name);
        } else if (classes.containsKey(name)) {
            byte[] classBytes = classes.get(name);
            Class clazz = defineClass(name, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
            loadedClasses.put(name, clazz);
            return clazz;
        } else {
            return super.loadClass(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to use `Play.application().resourceAsStream()` like this:

```java
private static final ClassLoader classloader = new JarClassLoader(new InputStream[]{
            Play.application().resourceAsStream("path/to/file.jar")
    }, ThisClass.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is most likely that in Play dist, your jar file is packaged inside another jar file, which means the URL looks something like jar:file:///path/to/jar/file.jar!your/embedded/jarfile.jar.